# Image loads by default instead of remaining hidden with JQuery: Image on Scroll Down Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm a jquery newbie trying to make my logo remain hidden and only appear when I scroll down.

**The problem with the following jquery code is that it makes my logo appear when I load the site**

The code only works as intended when I scroll once, however I want to make the jquery load the page with the image hidden. How can I fix the following code to accomplish this?

```
<script>
(function($) {
    var $logo = $('.logo');
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
       $logo.css({display: $(window).scrollTop() > 300 ? "block":"none"});
    });
})(jQuery)</script>
```

Comment: Use css to put `display:none` to your logo and when the page load it will not appear at first.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe it was that simple of fix. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You should load the `css` with that element hidden or withuot displaying it.

You can either do it directly from css (I recommend that) as:

```
.logo{
    display: none;
    // or
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or, do it with jQuery as:

Above the `var $logo = $('.logo');` add `$('.logo').css('display','none');`.

Then to make it visible again, `$('.logo').css('display','block');`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I suggest against using Javascript on page load to hide elements as it will still appear on the page for some milliseconds until the Javascript downloads and runs. CSS is the way to go.